# How to create a C# enum property that works in the Xamarin.iOS visual designer?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am currently developing an iOS component that inherits from `UIView` that can be visually designed using Xamarin for Visual Studio.

I have an `enum` defined as:

```
public enum UIViewBorderStyles
{
    Top,
    Bottom,
    None
}
```

My component is set up in the following manner:

```
[Register("BorderView"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public partial class BorderView : UIView, IComponent
{
    ...

    [Export("BorderWidth"), Browsable(true)]
    public nfloat BorderWidth { get; set; }

    [Export("BorderStyle"), Browsable(true)]
    public UIViewBorderStyles BorderStyle { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The `BorderWidth` property displays when I add a `BorderView` using the visual designer, however the `BorderStyle` property (as an `enum`) does *not* display.

**Is there a way that `enum` values can be used with properties in the Xamarin iOS visual designer?**

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/build-custom-controls-with-the-xamarin-designer-for-ios/

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the article link.  It seems that I used the same or similar approach, but the `enum` property does not display.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: After experimenting with the problem further, it appears that rebuilding the solution is not sufficient for the property to appear.  The `.xib` file of views which contain visually designed instances of `BorderView` must be closed and reopened after rebuilding.  The `enum` property then correctly displays as a drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I was able to find the answer.

The remedy to get the property to display in the visual designer was to close and re-open all `.xib` files for views which contained a visually designed `BorderView` instance after rebuilding the solution.

Simply rebuilding the solution without closing and re-opening `.xib` files of containing views was insufficient to see the added property from the visual designer.

Comment: FYI: That is for using the Xamarin iOS Designer, for using the Xamarin-based custom UIView with Xcode's IB, you will need to enable it to be `@IBDesignable`...